# PHP - Only show result if the record is 15 minutes older than the duplicate

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

What I'm trying to achieve: If there are duplicates, check if the last record was 15 minutes older than the one just created, and if it is, then count it, if not, then ignore it.

```
public function count_log($pid)
{
    if($pid != FALSE) {

        $this->db->where('pid', $pid);
        $this->db->from('entries_log');
        $count_log = $this->db->count_all_results();
        return $count_log;

    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

I don't even know how to start with this. Any hlep is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use something like this:

```
<?php 
public function count_log($pid = NULL)
{
   if($pid) {
       $getLogMinutes = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H"), (date("i")-15), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
       $this->load->database();
       $this->db->where('pid', $pid);
       $this->db->from('entries_log');
       $this->db->where('your_datetime_field_log <', $getLogMinutes);
       $count_log = $this->db->count_all_results();

       if($count_log > 0){
         return $count_log;
       }   
       return false;
     } 
     else // Error if pid is not defined
     {
       return false;
     }
   }
?>
```

The your_datetime_field_log must be  a date, datetime, timestamp like field in your database to this code work.

Comment: Had used something similar. Thanks for the answer though.